# Rotating and flipping a triangle with pop

Tags: ios, objective-c, rotation, cashapelayer, facebook-pop

I'm having problems trying to flip a triangle up/down or left/right with pop framework (https://github.com/facebook/pop).

How can I convert the code I have into pop?

```
- (void)rotate {
    NSInteger left = self.Left;
    NSInteger middle = self.Middle;
    NSInteger right = self.Right;
    self.Left = middle;
    self.Middle = right;
    self.Right = left;

    //this works 
    //_baseLayer.transform = CATransform3DConcat(_baseLayer.transform, CATransform3DMakeRotation(degreesToRadians(120), 0,0,1));

    //rotate with pop, at some point this starts to rotate more than 120
    POPSpringAnimation *rotateAnimation = [POPSpringAnimation animationWithPropertyNamed:kPOPLayerRotation];
    rotateAnimation.toValue = @([rotateAnimation.fromValue floatValue] + 120/360.0f*(2*M_PI));
    rotateAnimation.springBounciness = 10.0f;
    rotateAnimation.springSpeed = 25.0f;        
    [_baseLayer pop_removeAnimationForKey:@"kAnimationRotate"];
    [_baseLayer pop_addAnimation:rotateAnimation forKey:@"kAnimationRotate"];
}

- (void)flipUpDown {
    _baseLayer.transform = CATransform3DConcat(_baseLayer.transform, CATransform3DMakeRotation(M_PI, 1.0f, 0, 0));        
}

- (void)flipLeftRight {
    NSInteger left = self.Left;
    NSInteger right = self.Right;
    self.Left = right;
    self.Right = left;

    _baseLayer.transform = CATransform3DConcat(_baseLayer.transform, CATransform3DMakeRotation(M_PI, 0, 1.0f, 0));
}
```

Comment: What have you tried? There are many links to examples from the pop repo README

Comment: My problem with pop is that I don't know how to make it continue from it's current state. With the above code I'm adding to the current transform.

Comment: Eg. in my rotate method I need to rotate it 120 degree every time it's called. I know that if there is no fromValue in pop, then it should use the current value and animate to toValue. But can't figure out how to do a toValue = fromValue + 120 degree

Comment: `toValue = @(fromValue.floatValue + 120/360.0f*(2*M_PI))`

Comment: @combinatorial that gives some weird rotations - every 3rd time it rotates, it rotates more than 120 degrees.

Comment: Can you update the question with the code you are using?

Comment: Updated with the pop animation code

Answer (score 0):

At the point you are using `fromValue` it won't be initialized. Try this code...

```
[_baseLayer pop_removeAnimationForKey:@"kAnimationRotate"];
//rotate with pop, at some point this starts to rotate more than 120
POPSpringAnimation *rotateAnimation = [POPSpringAnimation animationWithPropertyNamed:kPOPLayerRotation];
[_baseLayer pop_addAnimation:rotateAnimation forKey:@"kAnimationRotate"];
rotateAnimation.toValue = @([rotateAnimation.fromValue floatValue] + 120/360.0f*(2*M_PI));
rotateAnimation.springBounciness = 10.0f;
rotateAnimation.springSpeed = 25.0f;
```